# Application gives the error as null pointer exception during TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

//Class1 Code

```
int TestCaseID;
public  WebDriver driver =null;

@Parameters({ "browser" })  
@BeforeMethod
public void BrowserOpen(String browser) throws Exception {
    BaseClass Base = new BaseClass();
    this.driver = Base.OpenBrowser(browser);
}
```

//Base class

```
public WebDriver driver = null;

    public WebDriver OpenBrowser(String browser) throws Exception
    {           
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ReadPropertyFile.ReadProperty("ChromePath"));
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(ReadPropertyFile.ReadProperty("URL"));


        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(ReadPropertyFile.ReadProperty("URL"));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ReadPropertyFile.ReadProperty("IEPath"));
            driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(ReadPropertyFile.ReadProperty("URL"));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

        }
        return driver;

    }
```

I am invoking web driver in another class and returns driver from that class. 
But issue happening is when code goes out of the `@BeforeMethod` it gives exception as null pointer exception as below.I have added both the base class code and actual code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at commonLibrary.BaseClass.SafeInput(BaseClass.java:83)
    at pageFactoryMethods.LoginPageMethod.fnLogin(LoginPageMethod.java:32)
    at pageFactoryTestCases.LoginPageTestCases.TC1(LoginPageTestCases.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: Provide your BaseClass code

Comment: Please check the code above i have updated the same

Comment: Can you check whether the `browser` variable contains valid browser name?

Comment: It is opening correct browser and entering proper URL...but after control goes out of the BrowserOpen() method it gives the exception as null pointer exception